# Let $A$ = {2, 3, 4, 7} and $B$ = {1, 2, 3, ..., 12}. Define $aSb$ if and only if $a | b$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I just started learning about set relations and there is a question in the book

> Let $A$ = {2, 3, 4, 7} and $B$ = {1, 2, 3, ..., 12}. Define $aSb$ if and only if $a | b$. Use the roster method to describe $S$

It seems to me that I need to find instances of $a$ related $b$ when the criteria $a | b$ is met, but the only time I have seen the bar ($|$)is to indicate "such that" in set-builder notation(example, ${ n | n > 0 } = {1,2,3,...}$) and in that context, the question doesn't make sense to me.

Is it asking for ordered pairs where $a$ related to $b$ such that $a$ such that $b$?

Can someone tell me how to interpret this question and solve it?

Comment: In this context $a|b$ means "$a$ divides $b$".   So $2S8$ because $2$ divides evenly into $8$ but $8\not S 2$ because $8$ does not evenly divide into $2$.

Comment: I'm not show what the "roster method" is but presumably you do.  So just describe which values evenly divide into which using the concepts vocabulary and notation of your class material.  Exampe $4S8$ but $7 \not S 11$, etc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a\mid b$ means "$a$ divides $b$". So $4S12$ but $7\not S 5$.